# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'strdate' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I tried this codes with 3-4 files as a test, it worked fine. But when I ran with 3,000+ files, the error message popped up saying **File "C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article\ap_final.py", line 51, in extract_data
    combid = matchcomp2 + "," + strdate + "," + matchw + "," + matchcount
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'strdate' referenced before assignment**

I searched and it looks like something with **global** is an issue. I simply do not understand what that means..Please help.

```
import os,csv,datefinder,re
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article\parsedarticles')

def matchwho(text_to_match):
    if 'This story was generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('1')
    elif 'This story includes elements generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Elements of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Portions of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Parts of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'A portion of this story was generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This sory was partially generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This story contains elements generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This story includes information generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This story was originally generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('1')
    else:
        return('3')


def extract_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file1:
        text1=file1.read()
#locate the date of the article
    matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1))
    if len(matches) > 0:
        date=matches[1]
        strdate = str(date)
    else:
        print 'No dates found'



#locate the name of the company2
    matchcomp2 = text1.split(' ', 1)[0]
#count the number of words in the article
    matchcount = re.search(r'(.*) words', text1).group(1).strip()
#determine the article
    matchw =str(matchwho(text1))
#list the returns in a line
    combid = matchcomp2 + "," + strdate + "," + matchw + "," + matchcount
#save in txt format
    with open('outfile.txt', "a+") as outfile:
        outfile.write("\n"+combid)

files = os.listdir("C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article\parsedarticles")
for file in files:
    if ".txt" in file:
        extract_data(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails when `len(matches) < 0`

```
def extract_data(filename):
...
    if len(matches) > 0:
        date=matches[1]
        strdate = str(date)
    else:
        print 'No dates found'
```

So if your conditional statement fails, `strdate` never gets set. However,

```
combid = matchcomp2 + "," + strdate + "," + matchw + "," + matchcount
```

is dependent on that being set and assumes it will always be set.

Based on what you want to achieve there is several things you can do. One such example is this.

```
def extract_data(filename):
...
    if len(matches) > 0:
        date=matches[1]
        strdate = str(date)
    else:
        print 'No dates found in {}'.format(filename)
        strdate = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

*strdate* only defined for case len(matches) > 0, but used in any case during assigny to *combid*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are assigning strdate only when the len(matches) > 0 predicate is true, try to add a default strdate value either at the beginning or inside else clause to debug if that is the case.

It seems you are trying to call strdate but because the if condition is not true the code doesn't know what strdate is (since it hasnt been assigned yet due to the if statement being false).

That's my guess.